# How to read complete IP frames from TCP socket in Python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

I need to read a complete (raw) IP frame from a TCP stream socket using Python. Essentially I want an unmodified frame just as if it came off the physical line, including all the header information.

I have been looking into raw sockets in Python but I have ran into some issues. I don't need to form my own packets, I simply need to read and forward them verbatim.

So, how can I read an entire IP frame (incl. header) from an existing TCP socket (in Python)?

Preferably I'd like to use only standard libraries. Also, I am on a Linux host.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't "read an entire IP frame from a TCP socket" (no matter what language). TCP sockets don't provide access to raw packets. You will probably need to use a packet sniffing interface.

Comment: So what if I created a TCP server, is it possible to create a raw socket connected to the TCP port? Either way, I think I am going with a packet sniffing interface as suggested.

Comment: A raw socket has no "port" semantics! In your TCP server, the socket is created on a layer *above* the network's. All of the data it receives is stripped from the lower level layers by the OS already. The only way to get them is by sniffing raw packets and determine the type/port and other upper-level semantics yourself (or via some library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), which is not part of the standard library, and super speed isn't a requirement, you can use its `sniff` function. It takes a callback. Something like:

```
pkts_rxd = []
def process_and_send(pkt):
    pkts_rxd.append(pkt)
    sendp(pkt, 'eth1')
sniff(prn=process_and_send, iface='eth0', count=100)
```

You can run the sniff in a different thread or process, with `count=0` and stick the received packets on a queue if you want it to run forever. Just make sure that you put str(pkt) on the queue. I've seen weird things happen when putting scapy packets on `multiprocessing.Queue`s.

Debian and Ubuntu both have Scapy in their apt repositories. I don't know about rpm distros. It's pretty easy to install from source though: `./setup.py install`.

Comment: OK, this was definitely the way to go. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You should try [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [pylibpcap](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/) can do that.